# Flutter Can't Run Another Class Function

Tags: flutter

```
class _AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState
    extends State<_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? _animationController;

    final percentage = _animationController!.value * 100;
    
   void checkWork() {
    _animationController?.repeat();
    _animationController?.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }
   
 if (per <= _animationController!.value * 100) {
      _animationController?.stop();
    }
    
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        LiquidCustomProgressIndicator(
          value: _animationController!.value,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.red),
          shapePath: _buildHeartPath(),
          center: Text(
            "${percentage.toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        btnClick(),
      ],
    );
  }

  SizedBox btnClick() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              //_animationController.value+=25;
              checkWork();
            });
            Text("");
          },
          child: Text("")),
    );
  }
```

...

```
class diffrent{
    ...
        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              //_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicator;
                              setState(() {
                                animatedProgressIndicator.checkWork();
                              });}
```

When I tried to reach checkWork() func in another class project doesn't work as it should be but If I tap OutlinedButton in emulator it works, and I get that error "_animationController.value= expression compilation error". I just want to run checkWork() func in another class to connect classes.
What should I do?

Comment: move `checkWork` out from `build` function

Comment: I updated my question, still same actually